# How to clear css from select element?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a select element and no matter what I try, the option values are blank.  The number of options in the drop down is correct, but they are blank.  Here is the html:

```
          <label for="accountBrokerageName">Brokerage:</label>
          <select id="accountBrokerageName">
             <option value="Interactive Brokers, LLC"></option>
             <option value="Vanguard"></option>
          </select>
```

I'm assuming some css from another library is overriding the standard select>option css.  I've tried commenting out each linked library one at a time but no joy.  I've tried adding a .clear-css class to the option like this:

```
.clear-css {
  all:unset;
}
```

and append it to all options using jquery just before it is used, like this:

```
$('option').addClass('clear-css');
```

Still blank.

I've also tried

```
.clear-css {
  all:initial;
}
```

Still blank.

I also tried adding the clear-css class to the select element, but that causes the whole select element to disappear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to add the html content of options. Do `<option value="Interactive Brokers, LLC">Interactive Brokers</option><option value="Vanguard">Vanguard</option>`. It has nothing to do with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the values for each option between the opening and closing `<option>` tags. The value doesn't need to match the text content. In fact, it's usually better to remove any special characters and even spaces when working with external APIs, like this:

```js
// This JS is just for the sake of example, to log the new value with each change
const select = document.getElementById('accountBrokerageName');
select.addEventListener('change', () => console.log(select.value));
```

```html
<label for="accountBrokerageName">Brokerage:</label>
<select id="accountBrokerageName">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option...</option>
 <option value="interactive-brokers-llc">Interactive Brokers, LLC</option>
 <option value="vanguard">Vanguard</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well that's got to be the blunder of blunders of all time.  I tried everything but the obvious!  Too long staring at the code I guess.  But I learned something from you about the arrow function shortcut and the disabled selected technique.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Select values must be within the actual `<option>` tags:

```html
<label for="accountBrokerageName">Brokerage:</label>
<select id="accountBrokerageName">
 <option value="Interactive Brokers, LLC">Interactive Brokers, LLC</option>
 <option value="Vanguard">Vanguard</option>
</select>
```